# Create a wrapper function for malloc and free in C

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, malloc

I am trying to create wrapper functions for `free` and `malloc` in C to help notify me of memory leaks. Does anyone know how to declare these functions so when I call `malloc()` and `free()` it will call my custom functions and not the standards lib functions?

Comment: Side note, this is what tools like Valgrind do. If you'd rather use something out of the box on Unix or Linux, Valgrind is a good option.

Comment: Related: [What is the LD_PRELOAD trick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick/426260#426260)

Answer (score 85):

You have a few options:

1. **GLIBC-specific solution (mostly Linux).** If your compilation environment is `glibc` with `gcc`, the preferred way is to use [malloc hooks](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Hooks-for-Malloc.html). Not only it lets you specify custom `malloc` and `free`, but will also identify the caller by the return address on the stack.
2. **POSIX-specific solution.** Define `malloc` and `free` as wrappers to the original allocation routines in your executable, which will "override" the version from libc. Inside the wrapper you can call into the original `malloc` implementation, which you can look up using [`dlsym`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html) with `RTLD_NEXT` handle. Your application or library that defines wrapper functions needs to link with `-ldl`.

   ```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE
   #include <dlfcn.h>
   #include <stdio.h>

   void* malloc(size_t sz)
   {
       void *(*libc_malloc)(size_t) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
       printf("malloc\n");
       return libc_malloc(sz);
   }

   void free(void *p)
   {
       void (*libc_free)(void*) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "free");
       printf("free\n");
       libc_free(p);
   }

   int main()
   {
       free(malloc(10));
       return 0;
   }
   ```
3. **Linux specific.** You can override functions from dynamic libraries non-invasively by specifying them in the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable.

   ```
   LD_PRELOAD=mymalloc.so ./exe
   ```
4. **Mac OSX specific.**

   Same as Linux, except you will be using `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` environment variable.

Comment: Hi I am getting error, how to resolve? ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/tmp/libjmalloc.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.

Comment: @Thangaraj, I can't tell, this is a very generic error. It can be that the file isn't found, or compiled for the wrong architecture (x86 vs x86_64), or the lib isn't owned by the user owning the executable, if it has SUID bit set and the lib isn't owned by the owner of the executable (otherwise you could run your lib's code as other user).

Comment: Let me check this Alex. I have one doubt, this method will hold good for small programs. suppose if I have a large program, then how can I find out from where (which function) the malloc function is called.

Comment: Option 2 works well, until the application is run by valgrind, and then all sorts of odd problems happen. Is this due to valgrind doing a similar override and causing some sort of conflict? Which option is best suited for malloc wrapping with valgrind?

Comment: You are using printf() inside the custom malloc but printf() itself uses malloc. I'm getting segfaults with for example `LD_PRELOAD=./malloc.so ls`. Isn't this creating an infinite recursion? How to tell the functions inside our custom malloc to use the libc-malloc?

Comment: Your posix example gives a big segfault now.

Comment: See also this tutorial for how to build the `*.so` shared object: https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html.

Comment: If you override `malloc()` and `free()`, rather than simply wrapping them, you must take into account some special considerations, such as you may be creating infinite recursion if you call `printf()` from within `malloc()`, as `printf()` may call `malloc()`, which now calls `printf()`...forever until stack overflow. See my answer here on this: [“Segmentation fault (core dumped)” for: “No such file or directory” for libioP.h, printf-parse.h, vfprintf-internal.c, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68201136/4561887)

Comment: Additionally, here are some more tools you may need in your quest to override `malloc()`. Also my answer: [How to dynamically inject function calls before and after another executable's `main()` function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68219244/4561887)

Comment: Is 1) really a preferred way? It seems to be not thread safe, so it'll probably break for any modern program using threads.

Comment: malloc hooks are no longer an appropriate mechanism see for example - https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/08/25/securing-malloc-glibc-why-malloc-hooks-had-go - interposition is still a valid alternative - https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Replacing-malloc.html#Replacing-malloc

Answer (score 20):

You can do wrapper and "overwrite" function with LD_PRELOAD - similarly to example shown earlier.

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path.../lib_fake_malloc.so ./app
```

But I recommend to do this "slightly" smarter, I mean **calling dlsym once**.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void* malloc(size_t size)
{
    static void* (*real_malloc)(size_t) = NULL;
    if (!real_malloc)
        real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");

    void *p = real_malloc(size);
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc(%d) = %p\n", size, p);
    return p;
}
```

example I've found here: http://www.jayconrod.com/cgi/view_post.py?23 post by Jay Conrod.

But what I've found really cool at this page is that: **GNU linker provides** a useful option, **--wrap** . When I check "man ld" there is following example:

```
void *
__wrap_malloc (size_t c)
{
    printf ("malloc called with %zu\n", c);
    return __real_malloc (c);
}
```

I agree with them that's "trivial example" :). Even dlsym is not needed.

Let, me cite one more part of my "man ld" page:

```
--wrap=symbol
       Use a wrapper function for symbol.
       Any undefined reference to symbol will be resolved to "__wrap_symbol".
       Any undefined reference to "__real_symbol" will be resolved to symbol.
```

I hope, description is complete and shows how to use those things.

Comment: Hi I am getting error, how to resolve? ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/tmp/libjmalloc.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.

Comment: Strange. In past it worked, currently I got the same error as you. As I google it, there are many many similar cases. Please, let us know, when you find solution. I tried and couldn't - 'file' shows that binaries are same arch, so it should work. It needs more attention.

Comment: I had problem in two systems, in one system I corrected by replacing relative path with absolute path and in other system still digging :). I have one doubt, this method will hold good for small programs. suppose if I have a large program, then how can I find out from where (which function) the malloc function is called.

Comment: Good you've wrote, that full path works in one of your two configurations. I've checked out. In my configuration it does not work, when path contains white-spaces or is too long. So simply, **copy libjmalloc.so into /tmp , and run** `LD_PRELOAD=/tmp/libjmalloc.so ./a.out` . It solves problem in my case. Does it help in yours?

Comment: Do you have any inputs for;  I have one doubt, this method will hold good for small programs. suppose if I have a large program, then how can I find out from where (which function) the malloc function is called.

Comment: @thangaraj If you want to know who is caller inside of callee, I would recommend changing or combining method with one of following: binary instrumentation [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144733/argument-forwarding-in-llvm/7150790#7150790) or tracing/debugging like [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/), or ptrace based [like sydbox or pinktrace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4567301#4567301) - [here are similar ideas about tracking memory allocations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7150705#7150705). Making breakpoints with gdb in malloc and checking backtrace sounds reasonable.

Comment: How does --wrap linker flag work with malloc calls inside glibc? I.e. will it also somehow rename malloc inside `strdup` to the wrapper?

Answer (score 14):

In my case I needed to wrap memalign/aligned_malloc under malloc. After trying other solutions I ended up implementing the one listed below. It seems to be working fine.

[mymalloc.c](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-s03/src/interposition/mymalloc.c).

```
/* 
 * Link-time interposition of malloc and free using the static
 * linker's (ld) "--wrap symbol" flag.
 * 
 * Compile the executable using "-Wl,--wrap,malloc -Wl,--wrap,free".
 * This tells the linker to resolve references to malloc as
 * __wrap_malloc, free as __wrap_free, __real_malloc as malloc, and
 * __real_free as free.
 */
#include <stdio.h>

void *__real_malloc(size_t size);
void __real_free(void *ptr);


/* 
 * __wrap_malloc - malloc wrapper function 
 */
void *__wrap_malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *ptr = __real_malloc(size);
    printf("malloc(%d) = %p\n", size, ptr);
    return ptr;
}

/* 
 * __wrap_free - free wrapper function 
 */
void __wrap_free(void *ptr)
{
    __real_free(ptr);
    printf("free(%p)\n", ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In C, the method I used was similar to:

```
#define malloc(x) _my_malloc(x, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define free(x) _my_free(x)
```

This allowed me to detect the line and file of where the memory was allocated without too much difficulty.  It should be cross-platform, but will encounter problems if the macro is already defined (which should only be the case if you are using another memory leak detector.)

If you want to implement the same in C++, the procedure is a bit more [complex](http://wyw.dcweb.cn/leakage.htm) but uses the same trick.

Comment: Best not to use leading underscores in names - they're mainly reserved to the implementation.

Comment: Right, he's using those values as defined in the implementation. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2.3/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, leading `__` and names starting with `_` and a capital letter are reserved by the standard. Names starting with a single underscore are not reserved, but they should be contained within the file, i.e. the linker shouldn't see them. So as long as `_my_malloc` and `_my_free` are static functions, it's ok. On the other hand, [redefining library functions is undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14770384/912144).

Comment: @Shahbaz: ISO/IEC 9899:2011, §7.1.3 **Reserved identifiers** says: — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
underscore are always reserved for any use._
— _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers
with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._  I believe that `_my_malloc()` as a static function falls foul of the second restriction.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, how so? `static void *_my_malloc(size_t)` is defined only in file scope in the ordinary name space (and it's not a struct/union/enum, so it doesn't even enter the tag name space).

Comment: @Shahbaz: Doesn't your comment that '_`static void *_my_malloc(size_t)` is defined in file scope in the ordinary name space_' collide head-to-head with the standard saying '_all identifiers that begin with underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in  the ordinary name space_'.  What am I missing?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I had interpreted the _reserved for use in file scope_ as possible to use so long as it is in the file scope, i.e. reserved for the programmers use (so long as it's in the file scope). Perhaps you are right, but if you look at [GNU's description of reserved names](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html), where it says (emphasis mine): _reserved names include all **external** identifiers (global functions and variables) that begin with an underscore (‘_’) and ..._ seems more compatible with my understanding (_they_ could be wrong though)

Comment: If you want to call malloc from my_malloc, you'll want to #undef malloc, in the source file that defines my_malloc (and friends)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a set of wrapper functions I used for years (and still do when I dip into C) to detect unfree'd memory, memory free'd multiple times, references to free'd memory, buffer overflows/underflows, and freeing memory that was not allocated.

ftp://ftp.digitalmars.com/ctools.zip

They've been around for 25 years and have proven themselves.

You could use the macro preprocessor to redefine malloc and free to use the mem package ones, but I recommend against it, because it won't redirect library calls to malloc like what strdup does.

Comment: Auth protected link

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is to eliminate memory leaks, an easier, less intrusive way is to use a tool like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (free) or [Purify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/) (costly).

Comment: Agree.  Valgrind is awesome.  I like how it works with compiled binaries.  You don't need to compile it special or anything although you'll get the best results if you compile with -O0 and -g flags.

Answer (score 2):

If you define your own functions for malloc() and free() and explicitly link that with your applications, your functions should be used in preference to those in the library.

However, your function called 'malloc' cannot then call the library malloc function, because  in 'c' there's no concept of separate namespaces. In other words, you'd have to implement the internals of malloc and free yourself.

Another approach would be to write functions my_malloc() and my_free(), which call the standard library ones. This would mean that any code calling malloc would have to be changed to call your my_xxx functions.

Comment: And you can #define malloc my_malloc to get your code to work without modification. But you'll need to be consistent about usage - don't use my_malloc if the memory will be freed in a library, or vice versa.

Comment: Paragraphs 2 and 3 are misleading.

Comment: @Matt Joiner - can you elaborate, please?

Comment: P2: If there were namespaces it still wouldn't change the situation. Also you *can* subsequently call the real malloc function. This has nothing to do with C.
P3: Yes you could, and this wouldn't be hooking calls to malloc/free properly in code you didn't have control over. You *can* instruct the linker to redirect references to different names. Without modifying the C code.
Summary: None of the limitations you claim really exist, and none of the workarounds you have given are necessary.

Comment: @Matt - Thanks: I wasn't aware of malloc hooks and --wrap, BUT _they are highly toolchain and os specific_. Only gcc supports them, AFAICT - and the OP didn't specify OS or tools. C++ namespaces could provide a similar hack to the #define approach, but I'd agree it's far from ideal and suffers the problem you mentioned. In general, I'm still happy with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the only client of the custom `malloc` and `free` (i.e. you're not trying to monkey patch those methods for code in some other library), then you can use dependency injection.

```c
#ifndef ALLOCATOR_H
#define ALLOCATOR_H

#include <stddef.h>

struct Allocator;

typedef struct {
    void *(*allocate)(struct Allocator *allocator, size_t size);

    void (*free)(struct Allocator *allocator, void *object);
} AllocatorVTable;

typedef struct Allocator {
    const AllocatorVTable *vptr;
} Allocator;

typedef struct {
    Allocator super;
    char *buffer;
    size_t offset;
    size_t capacity;
} BufferedAllocator;

void BufferedAllocator_init(BufferedAllocator *allocator, char *buffer, size_t capacity);

typedef Allocator MallocAllocator;

void MallocAllocator_init(MallocAllocator *allocator);

void *Allocator_allocate(Allocator *allocator, size_t size);

void Allocator_free(Allocator *allocator, void *object);

#endif
```

```c
#include "allocator.h"
#include "malloc.h"

void *Allocator_allocate(Allocator *allocator, size_t size) {
    return allocator->vptr->allocate(allocator, size);
}

void Allocator_free(Allocator *allocator, void *object) {
    allocator->vptr->free(allocator, object);
}

void *BufferedAllocator_allocate(Allocator *allocator, size_t size) {
    BufferedAllocator *bufferedAllocator = (BufferedAllocator *) allocator;
    if (bufferedAllocator->offset + size > bufferedAllocator->capacity) {
        fprintf(stderr, "buffer overflow: %ld + %ld > %ld\n",
                bufferedAllocator->offset, size, bufferedAllocator->capacity);
        return NULL;
    }
    bufferedAllocator->offset += size;
    return bufferedAllocator->buffer + bufferedAllocator->offset - size;
}

void BufferedAllocator_free(Allocator *allocator, void *object) {

}

const AllocatorVTable bufferedAllocatorVTable = {
        .allocate = BufferedAllocator_allocate,
        .free = BufferedAllocator_free,
};

void BufferedAllocator_init(BufferedAllocator *allocator, char *buffer,
                            size_t capacity) {
    allocator->super.vptr = &bufferedAllocatorVTable;
    allocator->buffer = buffer;
    allocator->offset = 0;
    allocator->capacity = capacity;
}

void *MallocAllocator_allocate(Allocator *allocator, size_t size) {
    return malloc(size);
}

void MallocAllocator_free(Allocator *allocator, void *object) {
    free(object);
}

const AllocatorVTable mallocAllocatorVTable = {
        .allocate = MallocAllocator_allocate,
        .free = MallocAllocator_free,
};

void MallocAllocator_init(MallocAllocator *allocator) {
    allocator->vptr = &mallocAllocatorVTable;
}
```

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include "allocator_test.h"
#include "allocator.h"

void testAllocator() {
    {
        BufferedAllocator bufferedAllocator;
        char buffer[4];
        size_t capacity = sizeof(buffer);
        BufferedAllocator_init(&bufferedAllocator, buffer, capacity);
        Allocator *allocator = &bufferedAllocator.super;

        void *chill = Allocator_allocate(allocator, capacity);
        assert(chill == buffer);
        void *oops = Allocator_allocate(allocator, 1);
        assert(oops == NULL);
    }

    {
        MallocAllocator allocator;
        MallocAllocator_init(&allocator);

        void *chill = Allocator_allocate(&allocator, 100);
        assert(chill != NULL);
        void *alsoChill = Allocator_allocate(&allocator, 100);
        assert(alsoChill != NULL);
    }
}
```

So you would pass around an `Allocator *` to whichever piece of code you write that wants to allocate stuff (beyond something like `char buf[n]` on the stack). You can use a `MallocAllocator` to just use the system `malloc`/`free`, or you could use a `BufferedAllocator` at the very top of your program. A `BufferedAllocator` is just an example of a really simple malloc/free. It works well in my use-case because I pretty much know how much memory my program will use in advance, and I don't delete any object until the entire program is done. Using this interface, you could write a more complicated algorithm like one of the ones described in [this lecture](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/%7Ecollberg/Teaching/553/2011/Handouts/Handout-6.pdf). There are a lot of different strategies for preventing fragmentation and many trade-offs, so rolling your own malloc/free could be really useful.

Comment: like you solid approach, will implement using i_p_c naming convention

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, you can use malloc_hook() (with GNU glibc).  This function allows you to have malloc call your function prior to calling the actual malloc.  The man page has an example on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only talk about memory that you have under control, i.e. that you malloc and free on your own, you can take a look on [rmdebug](http://www.hexco.de/rmdebug/). Probably it is what you are going to write anyway, so you can save sometime. It has a very liberal licence, if that should be important for you.

I personally use it in a project, to look for memory leaks, the nice things is that it is much faster then valgrind, however it isn't that powerful so you don't get the full calling stack.