# Argument forwarding in LLVM

Tags: performance, function, llvm, argument-passing, callstack

I need some advice on "forwarding" arguments to a callee (in the LLVM-IR).

Suppose I have a function `F` that is called at the beginning of **all** other functions in the module. From `F` I need to access (read) the arguments passed to its immediate caller.

Right now to do this I box all arguments in the caller inside a struct and pass a `i8*` pointer to the struct to `F`, alongside an identifier telling which caller `F` is being called from. `F` has then a giant switch that branches to the appropriate unboxing code. This must be done because the functions in the module have differing signatures (differing argument/return value count and types; even differing calling conventions), but it is obviously suboptimal (both from a performance and code size point-of-view) because I need to allocate the struct on the stack, copy the arguments inside of it, passing an additional pointer to `F` and then performing the unboxing.

I was wondering if there's a better way to do this, i.e. **a way to access from a function** the stack frame of its immediate caller (knowing, thanks to the identifier, which caller the function was called from) or, more in general, **arbitrary values defined in its immediate caller**. Any suggestions?

note: the whole point of what I'm working on is having a **single** function `F` that does all this; splitting/inlining/specializing/templating `F` is not an option.

---

to clarify, suppose we have the following functions `FuncA` and `FuncB` (note: what follows is just pseudo-C-code, always remember we are talking about LLVM-IR!)

```
Type1 FuncA(Type2 ArgA1) {
  F();
  // ...
}

Type3 FuncB(Type4 ArgB1, Type5 ArgB2, Type6 ArgB3) {
  F();
  // ...
}
```

what I need is an efficient way for the function `F` to do the following:

```
void F() {
  switch (caller) {
    case FuncA:
      // do something with ArgA1
      break;
    case FuncB:
      // do something with ArgB1, ArgB2, ArgB3
      break;
  }
}
```

as I explained in the first part, right now my `F` looks like this:

```
struct Args_FuncA { Type2 ArgA1 };
struct Args_FuncB { Type4 ArgB1, Type5 ArgB2, Type6 ArgB3 };

void F(int callerID, void *args) {
  switch (callerID) {
    case ID_FuncA:
      Args_FuncA *ArgsFuncA = (Args_FuncA*)args;
      Type2 ArgA1 = ArgsFuncA->ArgA1;
      // do something with ArgA1
      break;
    case ID_FuncB:
      Args_FuncB *ArgsFuncB = (Args_FuncB*)args;
      Type4 ArgB1 = ArgsFuncB->ArgB1;
      Type5 ArgB2 = ArgsFuncB->ArgB2;
      Type6 ArgB3 = ArgsFuncB->ArgB3;
      // do something with ArgB1, ArgB2, ArgB3
      break;
  }
}
```

and the two functions become:

```
Type1 FuncA(Type2 ArgA1) {
  Args_FuncA args = { ArgA1 };
  F(ID_FuncA, (void*)&args);
  // ...
}

Type3 FuncB(Type4 ArgB1, Type5 ArgB2, Type6 ArgB3) {
  Args_FuncB args = { ArgB1, ArgB2, ArgB3 };
  F(ID_FuncB, (void*)&args);
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you've done it right. While there are solutions in machinecode assembly, I am afraid there might be no solution in LLVM assembly, as it's "higher level". If you'd like to run a function on the beginning of some functions have you thought about checking

- debugger sources (like gdb)
- Binary Instrumentation with [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

I know it's not direct answer, but I hope it might be helpful in some way ;).

Comment: dtrace did the very same as CAFxX describes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but I had a similar problem and got around the limitations of LLVM's tbaa analysis by using a llvm vector to store the intermediate values. LLVM optimization passes were later able to optimize the vector load / stores into scalar registers.

There were a few caveats as I recall. Let me know if you explore this route and I can dig up some code.