# Overriding malloc to log allocation size

Tags: c, malloc

i'm trying to use a little bit of code to log mallocs in tcpdump for a project of mine, the code i'm using is thus:

```
#include <stdlib.h>


unsigned int memCount = 0;

void *my_malloc(size_t size) {
void *p = malloc(size);
memCount = memCount + size;
printf("Memory Allocated :%u \n", size
return p;
}

#define malloc(size) my_malloc(size)
```

After looking at many similar questions online it seems that this should work, however my custom malloc does not seem to be getting called. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262439/create-a-wrapper-function-for-malloc-and-free-in-c

Comment: are you overriding `malloc` in your code or already compiled code? also, make sure your macro is defined at a global level, being visible to every use of `malloc`

Answer (score 1):

You have to `#define` the malloc macro in each source file again - thus do it by including a header file where the macro is defined.

Comment: This is not the problem. The problem is that the `my_malloc` ends up calling itself.

Comment: This is not what the OP asked, sorry. However, just don't ``#include`` that header file in the source file defining ``my_malloc()``, instead ``#include`` the ``stdlib.h`` file. Also be aware that you have to include the header file re-defining ``malloc()`` _after_ the ``stdlib.h``.

Answer (score 0):

It should, you're probably not making the `define` visible to the file you're actually using `malloc` in. Put it in a common header, that is included by all your implementation files.

EDIT: If the problem is the function is calling itself, you should move the `define` **after** the function declaration.

Comment: malloc isn't a *keyword*, its a function name, which you are free to replace if you override the default RT

Comment: malloc is the name of a library function, not a keyword.

Comment: `malloc` is not a keyword (reserved identifier), but I imagine it may be a implemented as a macro for another identifier (`#define malloc __Malloc`).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `#define` for `malloc` is called by your `my_malloc` when you are expecting the real `malloc` to be called. The reason for that is that the preprocessor also converted the `malloc` in there to `my_malloc`.

If we simply preprocess the following:

```
#define malloc(size) my_malloc(size)

unsigned int memCount = 0;

void *my_malloc(size_t size) {
  void *p = malloc(size);
  memCount = memCount + size;
  printf("Memory Allocated :%zu \n", size);
  return p;
}

int main(void) {
  malloc(123);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You'll actually get:

```
unsigned int memCount = 0;

void *my_malloc(size_t size) {
  void *p = my_malloc(size);
  memCount = memCount + size;
  printf("Memory Allocated :%zu \n", size);
  return p;
}

int main(void) {
  my_malloc(123);
  return 0;
}
```

You need to access the real `malloc`, which is demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262439/create-a-wrapper-function-for-malloc-and-free-in-c).