# how to check if memory is allocated using malloc or new

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

I am dealing with some legacy C/C++ code where memory is allocated using `malloc` as well as using `new`. I want to create a generalized wrapper function to deallocate the memory using either `free` or `delete []` , depending on how it is allocated.

Is there a way to determine how memory is allocated ? Here is a pseudo code.

```
double *x;
double *y;
x = (double *) malloc(size);
y = new double [size]

doSomething();
deallocateMemory(x, y);
```

I want `deallocateMemory` to determine whether to call `free` or `delete []` . Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702292/overriding-malloc-to-log-allocation-size

Comment: You should encode this in the type system using `std::unique_ptr` with an appropriate deleter.

Comment: often new is a direct forward to malloc and delete to free. As a result, all memory is allocated with malloc which is no problem at all. I can't see your intention of what you are doing. Can you explain a bit? Or do you try to manually call destructors while freeing memory? Thats a bad idea!

Comment: If you can't change the actual `malloc()` implementation as suggested in @DevSolar's answer, what I can think of is wrapping up all that legacy API's with a c++ interfacing API that keeps track of what's going on, and what came from where. I'm posting this as a comment, because an appropriate answer would become pretty broad without knowing more details about the legacy API.

Answer (score 6):

Wrap the raw pointers in appropriate smart pointers (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`) as soon as you take ownership.

Also, order a  [nine-tail cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_o%27_nine_tails) and flog the persons responsible for the mess.

[image]

Comment: LOL... they have left long ago but I am going to order one for sure ;-)

Comment: It is the most violent answer in StackOverflow's history! :-D

Answer (score 6):

You can implement `malloc()` yourself instead of using the implementation provided by the standard library. You can also overload the operators `new` and `delete`. Nothing keeps you from adding your own bookkeeping to either of these implementations, so yes, this is perfectly possible.

Is it recommended? No it isn't.

This smacks of an attempt at implementing garbage collection. If this is true, you are looking at C++ from the wrong way. C++ *does* have its cleanup facility, which is its destructors. There are ready-made implementations of pointer containers, which in their destructors clean up the allocated memory. Others have mentioned them, and I don't copy-paste from other people's answers.

Comment: When the problem is spaghetti, solutions should preferably be *very* simple -- and implementing book-keeping allocation is about the most complex one can do. In another similar question's answer it was attempted, and very very incorrect. Chances are, if the OP tries this, it will only exacerbate the problems, and waste a lot of time.

Comment: @DevSolar: actually I am trying to clear up the mess due to operloaded operators which is resulting in many problems! So, as you correctly said, I won't go that path. The legacy code has several convoluted  malloc / new allocations whose origins are difficult/time consuming to trace given the size of the code.. so I was checking if there is any way to query how the memory is allocated.

Answer (score 2):

You want to write

> *a generalized wrapper function to deallocate the memory*

then you need to write

> *a generalized wrapper function to **allocate** the memory*

and, it is not recommended at all. Try to make your goal clean. If you have to deal with `malloc/free` pointer in some part of your code and you can not modify `malloc` parts, then try not to mix that part with your `new/delete` part.

Otherwise, you have no standard way to determine what allocation method is used for a pointer.

Comment: When the problem is spaghetti, solutions should preferably be very simple -- and implementing book-keeping allocation is about the most complex one can do. In another similar question's answer it was attempted, and very very incorrect. Chances are, if the OP tries this, it will only exacerbate the problems, and waste a lot of time