# Redefining malloc for thread safety in FreeRTOS

Tags: c, malloc, std, c-preprocessor, freertos

Can I do something like this:

```
#ifdef FREERTOS

#define malloc(size) pvPortMalloc(size)
#define free(ptr) pvPortFree(ptr)

#endif
```

and expect it to always call `pvPortMalloc()` instead of `malloc()`?

Also, what difference would it make putting this before/after `#include <stdlib.h>`?

I have some code that I would like to run both in and out of FreeRTOS, I would like to replace all the calls to `malloc()` with calls to `pvPortMalloc()` when using FreeRTOS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a wrapper function for malloc and free in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262439/create-a-wrapper-function-for-malloc-and-free-in-c)

Comment: `pvPortMalloc` is routine of allocating memory of FreeRTOS which is deffer for different algorithem of heap allocation.FreeRTOS internallaly used it for allocation memory for task,queue etc. You can do wrapper `malloc` as you done by `#ifdef FREERTOS...#endif`. It's replace all `malloc` to `pvPortMalloc` if `FREERTOS` defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custome `malloc` as per your requirement. And already you have done also.

```
#ifdef FREERTOS

#define malloc(size) pvPortMalloc(size)
#define free(ptr) pvPortFree(ptr)

#endif
```

So when you want to use code with FreeRTOS then define `FREERTOS` flag. So  it will use `pvPortMalloc` for memory allocation defined by freeRTOS from different heap management schemes (heap_1.c,heap_2.c,heap_3.c or heap_4.c) .

Without FreeRTOS not require to define.So it will use inbuilt  `malloc` from `#include <stdlib.h>`

**Also, what difference would it make putting this before/after "#include"?**

I say no difference in it.

Comment: The C library internally will generally be linked to malloc, so this #define will not work. Especially on newlib, you need to have a strongly linked symbol for __malloc_r, which things like printf will use internally to allocate an internally used buffer. http://www.nadler.com/embedded/newlibAndFreeRTOS.html has some details.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work properly:

```
#define malloc(size) pvPortMalloc(size)
#define free(ptr) pvPortFree(ptr)
```

If you use printf, sprintf or some other functions from the standard library, it will call malloc_r, which isn't save for threads!

And yet, I have no idea how to redefine malloc and free

Comment: See http://www.nadler.com/embedded/newlibAndFreeRTOS.html for some hints. Generally you need to implement __malloc_lock and __malloc_unlock, and __malloc_r and friends.