# Trace libc and system call function calls on Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

I have a C++ application on Linux. How can I see library calls to functions such as `malloc()` and then on to system calls such as `sbrk()`, etc., throughout the execution of the program?

I would like this to show which libc functions occurred and responsible for the subsequent Linux system calls.

NB: I don't wish to intercept any function calls, just to log which C library functions called which system calls.

Answer (score 9):

> I would like this to show which libc functions occurred and responsible for the subsequent Linux sys calls.

### You may want to use [ltrace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) and/or [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html).

Of course read [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/). Or use [ld.so(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) tricks with [dynamic linkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker). You could read [*Linkers and Loaders*](http://iecc.com/linker)

I would believe that **compiling your application with all warnings and debug info** (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) **should help** (notably giving better output). You could even want to install the debugging variant of some system libraries (on Debian or Ubuntu, packages like `libstdc++6-4.8-dbg` etc...).

#### Only when you believe to have corrected most bugs recompile your code with [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) enabled

(that practically means: [add](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `-O2` to `g++` program options, so configure your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool appropriately, e.g. edit your `Makefile` if you use [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)).

If in 2020 you use a recent [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/), consider using its [static analyzer](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Static-Analyzer-Options.html) options. Consider also using [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).

You should also consider using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and, with recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compilers, [use](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) some [sanitizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) option (e.g. `-fsanitize=address`) and of course enable all warnings and [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug info (so pass also `-Wall -Wextra -g` to `gcc` or  `g++`).

And you could trace semi-automatically some functions using a recent [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger, since [`gdb` may be scriptable](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Extending-GDB.html) in Python or Guile.

Another approach (see [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report) would be to code your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) then use it while compiling some of your or other source code.

BTW, to understand how standard libraries work (i.e. which [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) they are calling) you could not only `strace` a program using them, but also, since **many libraries on Linux are [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) or [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source)**, so **download then study their source code**. I find the source code of [musl-libc](http://www.musl-libc.org/) very readable. See also the more common [Gnu libc](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/). And the C++ standard library is packaged inside [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/).

For a systematic approach, read [LinuxFromScratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/). With enough patience (weeks of work) you could compile all your Linux software (or use source based distributions like [Gentoo](https://gentoo.org/)).

Comment: This answer is enlightening! It deserves many more upvotes.

Answer (score 6):

you can start from:

```
man ld-linux
export LD_DEBUG=help
```

Example i woud like to know the ls command what kind of functions uses:

```
export LD_DEBUG=symbols
export LD_DEBUG_OUTPUT=myoutput.txt
[xxxx@localhost ~]$ ls -l
total 244
-rw-rw-r--   1 xxxxx pppppp    247 Jul 15 12:05 28_29storage.txt
```

Now in file myoutput.txt.pidnumber i have:

```
   13419:   symbol=malloc;  lookup in file=ls [0]
   13419:   symbol=malloc;  lookup in file=/lib64/libselinux.so.1 [0]
   13419:   symbol=malloc;  lookup in file=/lib64/libcap.so.2 [0]
   13419:   symbol=malloc;  lookup in file=/lib64/libacl.so.1 [0]
   13419:   symbol=malloc;  lookup in file=/lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
```

Answer (score 1):

For system calls you can use ltrace/strace as the previous answer mentioned. In order to trace libc calls, you need to decide which specific calls you want to trace and create a library that uses LD_PRELOAD to override them.

See [Create a wrapper function for malloc and free in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262439/create-a-wrapper-function-for-malloc-and-free-in-c) for details on how to do this.

Comment: You beat me to it, I wanted to see exactly what new() -> malloc() was doing with regards to sbrk()/mmap() etc.