# Wrap malloc / free in Android NDK

Tags: c++, c, android-ndk

Is it possible to wrap malloc / free functions in Android NDK?

I have checked all the solutions from [create-a-wrapper-function-for-malloc-and-free-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262439/create-a-wrapper-function-for-malloc-and-free-in-c) but none of them worked.

In the top-voted answer there are 4 approaches proposed:

1. Usage of hooks -> hooks are not available in bionic
2. Usage of dlsym -> crashes with 'SEGV_MAPERR'
3. not applicable for Android
4. not applicable for Android

Comment: ' none of them worked' what??  Why?  Not even as a straight pass-through?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: For Android you can use **libc.debug.malloc**: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/native-memory.html

Comment: *"Is it possible to wrap malloc / free functions in Android NDK?"* - Yes, use C++ :)