# How to redefine malloc/free in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I want to redefine malloc() and free() in my code, but when I run, two errors appear:

```
allowing all exceptions is incompatible with previous function "malloc";
allowing all exceptions is incompatible with previous function "free";
```

Then I search for this error, it seems CUDA doesn't allow us to redefine libary function, is this true? If we can't redefine those functions, how can I resolve the error?

Comment: Assuming that creating a wrapper for those functions is not enough for you, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262439/create-a-wrapper-function-for-malloc-and-free-in-c) question.

Comment: Also, [this](http://codinggorilla.domemtech.com/?p=504) post describes how to implement a hook for cudaMalloc in detail.

Comment: Is this basically your earlier question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565884/error-allowing-all-exceptions-is-incompatible-with-previous-function-malloc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very short answer is that you cannot.

`malloc` is fundamentally a C++ standard library function which the CUDA toolchain internally overloads with a device hook in device code. Attempting to define your own device version of `malloc` or `free` can and will break the toolchain's internals. Exactly how depends on platform and compiler.

In your previous question on this, you had code like this:

```
__device__ void* malloc(size_t)
{ return theHeap.alloc(t); }
__device__ void free(void* p)
{ the Heap.dealloc(p); }
```

Because of existing standard library requirements, `malloc` and `free`  must be defined as `__device__ __host__` at global namespace scope. It is illegal in CUDA to have separate `__device__` and `__host__`definitions of the same function. You could probably get around this restriction by using a private namespace for the custom allocator, or using different function names. But don't try and redefine anything from the standard library in device or host code. It will break things.

Comment: so, why can redefine new and delete?